# How to add multiple Detail View Controllers in Master-Detail application

Tags: ios, objective-c, master-detail, ipad

I am trying to build an iPad Master-Detail app. 
The master View is just a `TableViewController`.
I want to change the complete Detail view for every different cell the user taps in the Master View. 
One of the Detail view controllers has to allow the user to type data, the other to view something, etc. So How can I add more DetailViewControllers to a Master-Detail app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use replace segues for this purpose. Connect as many view controllers as you want directly from the master controller (not the cells) with replace segues, and give them all identifiers. In didSelectRowAtIndexPath:, implement whatever logic you need to relate the index path to which controller you want to segue to, and then call performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: to initiate the segue. If you need to pass any data on to the next controller, you can do that in prepareForSegue.

Answer (score -3):

"MultipleDetailViews" sample app from apple might help. Here is the link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html.  Also I believe there are other similar questions in stackoverflow.

Comment: true, lots of questions on this topic, but sometimes this doesn't mean one of them has a useful solution on one's specific problem. Thanks for the answer, though